# Script to change image position depending on countdown time

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking for a way (JavaScript or jQuery) to let a timer script change the position of a background- or regular image within a div.
There are many existing countdown scripts out there but they do not let me do what I want.

I'd like the image to slowly, depending on the countdown to a specific day in February (where our company celebrates her 20 years), change position upwards. Untill that specific day: then it should be exactly in the middle.

Here the image with the years of which only the highlighted part is visible.

[image]

The html will be something like:

```
<div class="imageholder" style="overflow:hidden;width:100px; height:118px;">
    <img src="pathtoimage" id="MovingImage">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think you need something like this :

**CSS** :

```
.imageholder{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 70px;
}
```

**jQuery** :

```
var start = '1/19/2017 00:00:00',
    end   = '2/10/2017 00:00:00', // timer will stop at this time
    topOffset = 118;              // style=" margin-top: -118px " at the end time

var img = $('#MovingImage');

start = new Date(start).getTime();
end   = new Date(end).getTime();

var t = end - start;

timer();

function timer(){
    var now = new Date().getTime(),
        pst = now - start,
        top = pst*topOffset/t*-1;

    if( top > topOffset)
        top = topOffset;
    else
        setTimeout(timer,1000);

    img.css({
        'margin-top': top
    });
}
```

You can customize this by `height: ...px;` , `start = '...'` , `end = '...'` and `topOffset = ...`

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/a2o65r9h/)**